# stdout backing up when sending multiple requests to spawned process

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I'm having a weird issue where when I spawn a process and keep that spawned process active for multiple requests, the stdout of that process seems to keep an active count of how many times its been called and used that count for stdout.on. In this example I'm spawning a simple bash script that echos out what's been passed to it, and the node file sends requests to this script through spawn. I've pasted what I think my results should be and what they actually are on the bottom. What is going on here?

// echo-me bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ 1 == 1 ]]; do
    read input
    echo "echoing $input"
done
```

// echo-me node script

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var cmd = spawn('./echo-me',[]);

function echoMe(conn,req,callback) {
    var res;
    conn.stdin.write(req+'\n');
    conn.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    conn.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        res = data.trim();
        console.log('1 -> '+res+':');
        return callback(res);
    });
}

echoMe(cmd,'test1', function(res) {
    console.log('2 -> '+res+':');
});

setTimeout(function() {
    echoMe(cmd,'test2', function(res) {
        console.log('2 -> '+res+':');
    });
},1000);

setTimeout(function() {
    echoMe(cmd,'test3', function(res) {
        console.log('2 -> '+res+':');
    });
},2000);
```

// expected results

```
1 -> echoing test1:
2 -> echoing test1:
1 -> echoing test2:
2 -> echoing test2:
1 -> echoing test3:
2 -> echoing test3:
```

// actual results

```
1 -> echoing test1:
2 -> echoing test1:
1 -> echoing test2:
2 -> echoing test2:
1 -> echoing test2:
2 -> echoing test2:
1 -> echoing test3:
2 -> echoing test3:
1 -> echoing test3:
2 -> echoing test3:
1 -> echoing test3:
2 -> echoing test3:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `on`, your event handler will be called every time you recieve some data on `stdout`.
You might want to use `once`, so your event handler will be immediately removed once the `data` event is fired.
Or you can remove old listeners with `removeListener(event, listener)` or `removeAllListeners(event)`.

Comment: Thanks, the 'once' tip works if my event is only fired once per function call but what do you do if each function call emits multiple events? I tried using removeAllListeners() like you suggested but that doesn't work. Here's a link to the updated code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/34758d03ca6f800229fc

Comment: Nevermind @lennoff, I figured out my second question. Here's a working example for those curious if they stumble upon this in the future. https://gist.github.com/grkblood13/dcf448a17bf563021530